# How to determine a document's name based on the previous document's name in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do you create documents with their names increasing with each creation?

For example, consider the following example from the firebase website:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections

```
collections_bookmark rooms

class roomA

name : "my chat room"

collections_bookmark messages

class message1

from : "alex"
msg : "Hello World!"

class message2

...

class roomB
```

My question is how do you create documents like message1, message2, message3 etc. so that the number in the name increases with each creation? What's the JS code like for that? Do you use Regular Expression with match by retrieving them all? Or is there a simpler way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The example in the documentation merely shows these document IDs, to clarify the structure and not as a recommendation to use sequential document IDs. Using sequential message IDs puts a significant throughput limit on the document writes that can be performed against your database.

I **highly** recommend using the auto-generated document IDs, and including a server-side timestamp in each document. You can then use the sorting/filtering functionality in the Firebase console to show the documents in your preferred order, without reducing the throughput capacity of your database.

Comment: Thank you for your continued support, Frank. What is throughput in the context of Firebase Storage? I read about what throughput is in Wikipedia and still a bit unsure. Thank you.

Comment: Your question was about Cloud Firestore, wasn't it? Cloud Firestore and Cloud Storage are very different products.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant Firestore.

Comment: If you're new to this, I'd honestly recommend just taking my word for it, as this is really all quite involved. But it boils down to that the amount of data you can write to Firestore in one time period is mostly determined by the I/O capacity of its disks. And using sequential IDs means that the data is closer together on disk, while the auto-generated IDs are spread out further. The latter means the data may be on multiple disks, which leads to being able to write more data per time period.